# Chronicle queue on maven central

Tags: chronicle-queue

I've found chronicle-queue version on maven central is quite old: 4.5.27, while 4.6.23 is most recent released on github. Does it mean 4.5.27 is a kind of "prod-ready", while all 4.5.27+ are experimental? Or you use other repositories for distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.5.27 version is stable and available to all users.

The 4.6.x version is being developed and available to supported clients. We expect to make a public release of this version this month.